# Crash when use crosswalk in Fragment

Tags: android, crosswalk

When I try to use XwalkView in fragment, application crash
                                                                 Log:android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class org.xwalk.core.XWalkView

so,I write a demo to test using the same method,it works.The h5 display well in the fragment

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: post your xml and java code

Comment: thx anyway, I use other framework instead